# com.calculator cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, testing, automated-tests

For automating application using robotium i have use this code.

```
 package com.calculator.test;

 import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

 import com.robotium.solo.Solo;

 public class TestMain extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
    private Solo solo;

    public TestMain() {
        super(com.calculator, Main.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    public void testDisplayBlackBox() {
        // Enter 10 in first editfield
        solo.enterText(0, "10");
        // Enter 20 in first editfield
        solo.enterText(1, "20");
        // Click on Multiply button
        solo.clickOnButton("Multiply");
        // Verify that resultant of 10 x 20
        assertTrue(solo.searchText("200"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }
}
```

But eclipse is showing error in

```
public TestMain() {

        super(com.calculator, Main.class);
...

}
```

for com.calculator and Main as `"Cannot be resolved to a type"`.

Is there any imports needed to avoid this error?

Comment: put code of `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`. does this class contain constructor that you tried to call?

Comment: @TBM ActitivityInstrumentationTestCase2 is the main class which is used for testing different functionality in Robotium. So i have imported the class in this test. i dont know whether it has the same constructor. Please check this [link](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/276/bfraser/other/TestAndroidSampleApp-3_0.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The doc here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html says the first paramater of the constructor should be a String.

Your code should be

```
public TestMain() {
    super("com.calculator", Main.class);
}
```

In which package is defined the class Main? Is it visible from you code?